# Configuring log4j at runtime

Tags: ant, log4j

I'm using org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener to manage logging with my ant script.  The ant script is highly configurable and designed to be run different ways with different parameters and therefore I need to be able to log to files specified at runtime.  I have a log4j.properties which specifies a log file to be build.log, and despite my attempts to launch ant redefining properties defined in log4j.properties have been unsuccessful.

The build ignores them and continues to write to build.log.  I haven't found much support regarding writing to custom files unless it's in Java with their Logger class.

Perhaps I'm thinking this through wrong.  log4j.properties isn't treated in the same way as a property file in an ant script (hence overrideable from the command line)?  Is there a way I can do this intelligently without writing a custom task or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setup your log4j.properties file using a system property that you can define dynamically on the command line.  The property below is "${logfile.name}".  An example log4j configuration would be like this:

```
# logfile is set to be a RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p]%d{yyyyMMdd@HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}\:%c - %m%n
```

The command line option to pass a property, when calling "ant", is "-Dlogfile.name={runtime path/filename of log file}".  Replace {runtime path/filename of log file} with your file name.  When ant is run this value is set as a system property.  That system property is then substituted into the log4j.properties at runtime.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html